# Zend Framework: Finding the path to the root of the application

Tags: apache, zend-framework

in zend framework, i usually setup `vhosts` so that i can refer to my static resources like js, css via "`/css/styles.css`" but what if i dont setup `vhost`s? my path to the static resources will be like "`http://localhost/app1/css/styles.css`". is there a way to find find what is the proper path to `css/styles.css` without hardcoding the "prefix" `http://localhost/app1/`? if done properly, i shld be able to move my app from `http://localhost/app1` to `http://localhost/a/deeper/path/app2/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the BaseUrl View-Helper

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('/css/global.css')) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/css/global.css') ?>
```

is how I set mine up.  Make sure the appropriate corresponding paths are set in the index.php and config.ini.  See the Zend Framework quickstart for more information if necessary.

Comment: thats how i set mine too. but that will only work if u setup `vhosts` if u didnt, and the url of your app looks like `http://localhost/some/path/zf/public`, the css will point to `http://localhost/css/global.css` which is wrong. i know that in production, url wont look like this but i am currently developing, and maynot want to setup vhosts